# Change the selected page in pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, pagination

I am using TWBS Pagination from the following URL:

[TWBS Pagination](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/)

And I have the following images:

1. [First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epJGw.jpg)
2. [Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUbgF.jpg)

From the second image, I have input "3" into the input box and click "Go" button, but the selected page in pagination remains from the last selected page.

Here is the code of pagination, input box and go button:

```
$('#pagination-mode').twbsPagination({
            totalPages: 50,
            visiblePages: 5,
            onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                $('#txtPage').val(page);
            }
        });

        $('#spanPage').text("Go");

        <button id="btnPage" type="button" class="btn pull-right">
           <span id="spanPage"></span>
        </button>
        <input type="text" id="txtPage" class="dark-control pull-right" />
```

My question is, how can I make the selected page in the pagination is following whatever value in the input box?

Your answer much appreicated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a click event handler for `#btnPage` button. And change the page on `#pagination-mode`

```
$('#btnPage').on('click', function() {
    $('#pagination-mode').twbsPagination('show', $('#txtPage').val());
});
```

If you have already written a click handler, you can just call the `show` function of `twbsPagination` inside that with the page number.